# NativeScript with angular gives a run time error

Tags: nativescript-angular

I just tried a connect  with my Native-script app.In app.component.ts file i have create my database and two methods.

```
export class AppComponent { 
private database: any;
private people: Array<any>;

public constructor() {
console.log(" database service constructors");
(new Sqlite("my.db")).then(db => {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstName TEXT, lastName Text)").then(db => {
    this.database = db;
  }, error => {
    console.log("CREATE TABLE ERROR", error);
  })
}, error => {
  console.log("CREATE DB ERROR", error);
})}
public insert() {
console.log("Acess Insert Ok");
this.database.execSql("INSERT INTO people (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?,?)", ["Randika", "Perera"]).then(id => {
  console.log("Insert Ok");
  this.fetch();
}, error => {
  console.log("INSERT ERROR: ", error);
})}
public fetch() {
this.database.all("SELECT * FROM people").then(rows => {
  this.people = [];
  for (let row in rows) {
    this.people.push({
      "id": rows[row][0],
      "firstName": rows[row][1],
      "lastName": rows[row][2]
    })
  }

}, error => {
  console.log("SELECTOR ERROR:", error);
});}}
```

In app.component.hlml file:

```
<ActionBar title="My App">
<ActionItem text="Add" (tap)="insert()"></ActionItem>
```

But after clicking add button and it gives a error like

```
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1197)
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1061)
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1047)
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1028)
W/System.err(10737):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1018)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The relevant bits of the stacktrace are missing. Can you please open a prompt and run `adb logcat`, then tap the button again? I think it will reveal the problem.

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen I have tried. No results.
But Finally i could find answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

When i'm searching more on it in emulator there is a error like " execSql is not a function". so i change it to execSQL like i used top of the and now its working fine.